# Heist example not working: ‘hcCompiledSplices’ is not a record selector

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, heist

I'm trying to understand how to use Heist, but none of the examples I find seem to be working and I can't seem to find anyone else that's having the same issue that I am. I found some example code here:

https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/older-but-still-interesting/compiled-heist-insight-with-no-snap-in-sight

However, when I try to run the first example, I get the following error:

```
Main.hs:20:15:
    ‘hcCompiledSplices’ is not a record selector
    In the expression:
    mempty
        {hcCompiledSplices = "foo" ## splice,
        hcTemplateLocations = [loadTemplates "."]}
    In an equation for ‘heistConfig’:
        heistConfig
        = mempty
            {hcCompiledSplices = "foo" ## splice,
            hcTemplateLocations = [loadTemplates "."]}
    In the expression:
    do { let heistConfig = ...;
        heistState <- either (error "oops") id
                        <$> (runEitherT $ initHeist heistConfig);
        builder <- maybe (error "oops") fst
                    $ renderTemplate heistState "simple";
        toByteStringIO B.putStr builder }

Main.hs:22:15:
    ‘hcTemplateLocations’ is not a record selector
    In the expression:
    mempty
        {hcCompiledSplices = "foo" ## splice,
        hcTemplateLocations = [loadTemplates "."]}
    In an equation for ‘heistConfig’:
        heistConfig
        = mempty
            {hcCompiledSplices = "foo" ## splice,
            hcTemplateLocations = [loadTemplates "."]}
    In the expression:
    do { let heistConfig = ...;
        heistState <- either (error "oops") id
                        <$> (runEitherT $ initHeist heistConfig);
        builder <- maybe (error "oops") fst
                    $ renderTemplate heistState "simple";
        toByteStringIO B.putStr builder }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using `heist-0.14.*`? Some stuff moved around, cf. [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/snapframework/heist/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0140).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lenses seems to be the way to do things now.

Also, I change the template `simple.tpl` to use the tag `<h:foo>...</h:foo>` instead of just `<foo>...</foo>`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings  #-}

module Lib2 where

-- import Data.Monoid
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.Either
import Heist
import Heist.Compiled as C
import Control.Lens

runtime :: RuntimeSplice IO T.Text
runtime = liftIO $ do
    putStrLn "Write something:"
    T.pack <$> getLine

splice :: Splice IO
splice = return $ C.yieldRuntimeText $ runtime

main = do
    let heistConfig = emptyHeistConfig
          & hcTemplateLocations .~ [ loadTemplates "." ]
          & hcCompiledSplices .~  ( "foo" ## splice )
        reportErrors errs = error ("errors: " ++ unlines errs)
    heistState <- either reportErrors id <$> 
         (runEitherT $ initHeist heistConfig)
    builder <- maybe (error "oops") fst $
         renderTemplate heistState "simple"
    toByteStringIO B.putStr builder
```

Comment: Thanks!! Can you explain the `h:` part though? Why did you have to do that? Do I always have to do that now?

Comment: I did it because that's what the error message said. Try running with just the `<foo>` tag, and you'll see the full error message. Undoubtably the prefix is configurable.

Comment: Really? Because I just see `oops`.

Comment: Oh, additionally, namespaces are a new feature in 0.14 and can be disabled by setting `hcNamespace .~ ""`

http://snapframework.com/blog/2014/09/24/heist-0.14-released